# delphi How to pass an unknown class as parameter?

Tags: class, delphi, vcl, rtti

i have this code here :

```
type
  TMyColors = (mcWhite, mcRed, mcBlue);
  TMyFields = (mfField1, mfField2, mfField3);
....
implementation

uses
  TypInfo;
{$R *.dfm}

function Get_ClassFieldName(ATypeKind: TUnknown_Class; ADataIndex: Byte):string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName(System.TypeInfo(ATypeKind), Ord(ATypeKind(ADataIndex)));
end;

procedure TForm1.Btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Get_ClassFieldName(TMyColors, 0) + ' | ' + Get_ClassFieldName(TMyFields, 0));
end;
```

what i want is to replace my ***TUnknown_Class*** Parameter with the right one if it possible.

Comment: Passing an unknown class isn't a problem at all. The problem here is that `TMyColors` isn't a class. It is a type which isn't a class (specifically, in this case, an enumeration).

Comment: sorry for this Confused in names ...
so what should i use for that scenario plz..

Comment: Would it be enough to simply pass `TypeInfo(TMyColors)` instead of `TMyColors`? That's a normal `Pointer` value. `TypeInfo` is a compiler intrinsic function, not a normal function. That is why it can take just a type identifier. If you want to play with types directly, you need to use generics.

Comment: Pass the type info, or use a generic method to provide the type

Answer (score 1):

It is look like you just need to use TRttiEnumerationType.GetName().

```
type
  TMyColors = (mcWhite, mcRed, mcBlue);
  TMyFields = (mfField1, mfField2, mfField3);
implementation
uses
  TypInfo,RTTI;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Btn_1Click(Sender: TObject);
var st1,st2  : string;
    MyColors : TMyColors;
    MyFields : TMyFields;
begin
 MyColors:=mcRed;
 MyFields:=mfField3;
 st1:=TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(MyColors);
 st2:=TRttiEnumerationType.GetName(MyFields);
 ShowMessage( st1+ ' | ' + st2);
end;
```